# Is an outer array valid JSON for a REST api?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

When using MongoDB with Mongoskin in a Node.js webb app I can run `.find()` on a collection to fetch all its document. The result is a mongodb cursor. 
This cursor is then converted to an Array with the cursors `.toArray()` method.

```
[
  {
    _id: "53ea101656cb0c0407306405",
    key: "value", 
    ...
  }, 
  {
    _id: "53ea101656cb0c0407306405",
    key: "value", 
    ...
  },
  ...
]
```

But is this a valid JSON output for a REST Api?... or should i convert the outer array to an object?
Maybe it doesn't matter?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is [valid](http://jsonlint.com/) JSON, assuming you put quotes around your keys. REST does not specify the format that a JSON response must use, so do whatever is right for your application.

Comment: Actually, I found this http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-structure-top-level. Might be useful for someone more than me.

Comment: From that link, it looks like proper JSON style for this case would be an object with a field called "data" containing the array.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, this violates no rules of any kind, and is totally fine.

However, at the risk of overcomplicating the situation, I would caution that if you wish to add meta-data to the response about *this collection*, you might want to wrap the array in an object. For example, if you'd like to put some hypermedia links in the response body relating specifically to this collection (for self, or creation of new objects, or paging perhaps), it is unlikely that they would fit anywhere inside the array. You could put the links in the header, of course, that is up to you.

But in general, you may want to put some meta-data in the response body, so keep that in mind and make sure you try to future-proof this response as much as is reasonably possible.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are fine and are often preferred when fetching a collection.  Most JS REST libs (like Backbone) will work out of the box when an array is returned for a collection GET and would require a bit of extra code in order to extract the array.